# How to check and set Amazon Web Services SDK for iOS and Android to use HTTPS (SSL)?

Tags: android, ios, security, ssl, amazon-web-services

How can I check if the Amazon Web Services SDK for iOS and Android to use HTTPS (SSL) to encrypt requests ?

And if it is not using this, how can I set it?

I have read this [Making Secure Requests to Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928) but I don't understand how this
applies in the case of the iOS and Android SDKs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All AWS SDKs default to using SSL.

iOS:

- [Default iOS constructor](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Service/AWSService.m#L368) sets "unsafe" to NO.

Android:

- [setEndpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.html#setEndpoint%28java.lang.String%29) defaults to https if not supplied.
- [setRegion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.html#setRegion%28com.amazonaws.regions.Region%29) defaults to https unless changed in ClientConfig.